# To prepare a dataframe with elements being repeated from a list in python

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a list as `primary = ['A' , 'B' , 'C' , 'D']`
and a DataFrame as

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=dateRange, columns = ['Date'])
```

which contains 1 date column starting from 01-July-2020 till 31-Dec-2020.

I created another column `'DayNum'` which will contain the day number from the date like 01-July-2020 is Wednesday so the `'DayNum'` column will have 2 and so on.

Now using the list I want to create another column `'primary`' so that the DataFrame looks as follows:

In short, the elements on the list should repeat. You can say that this is a roster to show the name of the person on the roster on a weekly basis where Monday is the start (day 0) and Sunday is the end (day 6).

The output should be like this:

```
         Date  DayNum Primary
0   01-Jul-20       2       A
1   02-Jul-20       3       A
2   03-Jul-20       4       A
3   04-Jul-20       5       A
4   05-Jul-20       6       A
5   06-Jul-20       0       B
6   07-Jul-20       1       B
7   08-Jul-20       2       B
8   09-Jul-20       3       B
9   10-Jul-20       4       B
10  11-Jul-20       5       B
11  12-Jul-20       6       B
12  13-Jul-20       0       C
13  14-Jul-20       1       C
14  15-Jul-20       2       C
15  16-Jul-20       3       C
16  17-Jul-20       4       C
17  18-Jul-20       5       C
18  19-Jul-20       6       C
19  20-Jul-20       0       D
20  21-Jul-20       1       D
21  22-Jul-20       2       D
22  23-Jul-20       3       D
23  24-Jul-20       4       D
24  25-Jul-20       5       D
25  26-Jul-20       6       D
26  27-Jul-20       0       A
27  28-Jul-20       1       A
28  29-Jul-20       2       A
29  30-Jul-20       3       A
30  31-Jul-20       4       A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First compare column for `0` by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) with cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for groups for each week, then use modulo by [`Series.mod`](http://pgg.ndas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mod.html) with number of values in list and last map by dictioanry created by `enumerate` and `list` by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
primary = ['A','B','C','D']
d = dict(enumerate(primary))
df['Primary'] = df['DayNum'].eq(0).cumsum().mod(len(primary)).map(d)
```